# Real XML to .sdf database (changed data only, same schema) for Windows Mobile 6?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-6.5

I am working with SQL Server CE 3.5 for Windows Mobile 6 app development.

I have created a table in one `.sdf` data source. I was able to write xml from `.sdf` data pretty easily:

```
this.myDataSet.Titles.WriteXml("Out.xml");
```

However, I was never able to write a `.sdf` with data from `In.xml` (even that `In.xml` and `Out.xml` are the same for exception of changed data inside xml tags).

This what I used to try to write In.xml to `.sdf`:

```
this.myDataSet.Titles.ReadXml("In.xml");
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: The `.ReadXml` call only reads the data from the XML into the `DataSet` in memory - it doesn't save it to the database just yet. You need to save your data set contents to database after loading the XML!

Comment: THanks, marc_c. I didn't know that. But how do I save data set contents to database?

Comment: I still don't have my answer. How do I convert dataset to .sdf?